# How to get notified for send or cancel of an email

Tags: android, email-client

I am starting Email client using intent from my activity (Either native email or gmail). I just want to get notified into my activity when user presses send button or discards the email. I just want to start another activity when user press send button and want to show a dialog when user discards the email.

Here is my code

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"email@something.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Mail");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Test Mail Subject");
    startActivityForResult(emailIntent, REQ_CODE);


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == REQ_CODE){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "resultCode  "+resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){


        //}
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: instead of startActivty() method, user startActivtyForResult() method.

Comment: google it there a lots of SO post related to this

Comment: @Lucifer I tried startActivtyForResult(), but I am getting 0 as result code either send or cancel email.

Comment: @UsmanKurd I googled a lot, nothing worked that's why I posted here. Please remove downvote.

Comment: can you paste your code in the question please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. `ACTION_SEND` is not designed for use with `startActivityForResult()`, and nobody, let alone whatever email client the user happens to choose, is obligated to call `setResult()` to let you know what the user did.

Comment: Do you know any workaround for my problem. I want to know whether the email is sent or cancelled in my Activity???

Comment: @Aju: "Do you know any workaround for my problem" -- send the email yourself, such as using the JavaMail port for Android, or by sending it from your own account via a Web server.

Comment: I cannot use any third party Apis, as it is restricted for my current project.